# Autocomplete button for form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, autocomplete

First I want to say that I'm a learning noob so question can be easy for you. I have a form, which stores data in database1/table1 after completing the form. I have another table2 in database1 which includes usernames, full names and emails of my small office. I want to make a little button near the  field "username" of my form, so when I enter username to this field and press button near it, "full name" and "email" autocompletes from table2 to this form. Can anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to accomplish this task. You need to send username to the server side script and run a query on the basis of username. You will get full name and email of that particular username which you can show in your respective fields.

```
Ajax code:
username = $("#username").val();
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",   
    data:{username:username},
    url:"Your server side url goes here",
    success:function(result) {
       fetch your values here in result variable. 
    }
});
```